# Using SOAPAction in HTTP header to consume SOAP Service in JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, curl, soap-client

I'm trying to implement a soap service consumer in Java, using spring `WebServiceGatewaySupport`.

When I'm using `curl` to consume the service as below, it is giving proper response.

```sh
 curl -d @request.xml -H 'SOAPAction:abc:mnEvent#DoAction' https://myhost.org/cd/doAction.jsp
```

I'm trying to implement the same using JAVA, by adding following `HttpHeaders` in a template class inheriting from `WebServiceGatewaySupport`

```java
public O callWebService(String url, I request) {
    return (O) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(url, request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
            TransportContext transportContext = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
            HttpComponentsConnection connection = (HttpComponentsConnection) transportContext.getConnection();
            connection.getHttpPost().addHeader("SOAPAction", "abc:mnEvent#DoAction");
        }
    });
}
```

With this code, I'm getting an error message like below.

> SOP-330006 The method 'DoAction, ""' is not defined in SOAP service 'abc:mnEvent'.

What do I miss here when moving `curl` command to JAVA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `SOP-330006 The method 'DoAction, ""' is not defined in SOAP service 'abc:mnEvent'.` indicates, there are two soap actions in the request.

1. Explicit SoapAction added in HttpHeader
2. Implicit SoapAction in SoapMessage

To avoid this issue, we need to remove the soapAction from header and set it in SoapMessage.

```
SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
soapMessage.setSoapAction("abc:mnEvent#DoAction");
```